# what does "--" mean in Excel function

Tags: excel

seems it can just map TRUE/FALSE to 1/0. Couldn't find related documentation or answer here. Please help to advise.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [As everyone knows, a single minus sign in a formula causes Excel to change the sign of the result – for example, from positive to negative. But what do two minus signs in a formula do? Using two minus signs in an Excel formula causes the formula to transform a result of “True” into a value of “1” and a result of “False” into a value of “0.” Using two minus signs in a formula has no effect on any result other than “True” or “False.](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/143-using-two-minus-signs-in-excel)

Comment: Since True False is a one byte boolean, either 0 or 1 it can be represented in its numeric form by what @ditto said, multiplying by `-1 * -1` which returns the actual value.

Comment: @xQbert `Using two minus signs in a formula has no effect on any result other than “True” or “False"` That part, it can also be used to change a number that is stored as text back into a number, not just True or False, but say 526 that is stored as text back to its number.

Comment: Thanks xQbert and Scott! This is exact what i want.

Answer (score -1):

(I believe ...)

expanded, it's just:

```
-1*-1*K1
```

in other words, you're taking the numeric value, minus it twice ...

You can see this by putting the number "5" into K1 ...

you can also test this by putting "-6" in K1 and using then in L1, put: "-----K1" ... ;)

Comment: The test failed. Scott and xBert gave great answers in comments. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You may have typed in the test wrong, I tried it my end, and it just flips the negative sign ... depending on how many "-" you have .. ;)

Comment: if "minus it twice" in your answer means changing between positive and negative twice, then I agree. This is what I see in excel. Thanks for your answer.